# Running a bash shell script in java

Tags: java, shell

I want to run a shell script from my program below but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've run the same command directly in the linux terminal and it works fine so I'm guessing it's my java code. As you can see, I was first writing the command to the shell script using a PrintWriter but I expect that this would not effect the running of the shell script itself. Any help would be appreciated!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String nfdump = "nfdump -o csv -r /home/shane/Documents/nfdump/nfcapd.201211211526>blank.txt";

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/shane/Documents/script.sh");

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        pw.println("#!/bin/bash");
        pw.println(nfdump);

        pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Process proc = null;

    try {
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/shane/Documents/script.sh");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime.getRuntime()... When I use this I seem to have fewer problems and things appear a bit more undestandable

Comment: Curious why you are not directly executing `nfdump`

Comment: I want to be able to use nfdump from my GUI, it's part of the software I'm building

Comment: Can you check whether `script.sh` is empty?

Comment: Nope not empty! ProcessBuilder seems to work fine though!

Comment: Thanks to RNJ also for the ProcessBuilder tip

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should use the returned [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to get the result.

[`Runtime#exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) executes the command as a separate process and returns an object of type `Process`. You should call [`Process#waitFor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) so that your program waits until the new process finishes. Then, you can invoke [`Process.html#getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) on the returned [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object to inspect the output of the executed command.

An alternative way of creating a process is to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command%28java.lang.String...%29).

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```

With a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#command%28java.lang.String...%29), you list the arguments of the command as separate arguments.

See [Difference between ProcessBuilder and Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6856028/130224) and [ProcessBuilder vs Runtime.exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3997127/130224) to learn more about the differences between [`Runtime#exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) and [`ProcessBuilder#start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29).

Comment: Actually, if you're looking to retrieve the output of a subprocess then you'd need to call [`Process#getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29), which pipes to the process' output stream.

Answer (score 9):

When you execute a script from Java it spawns a new shell where the PATH environment variable is not 
set.

Setting the PATH env variable using the below code should run your script.

```
String[] env = {"PATH=/bin:/usr/bin/"};
String cmd = "you complete shell command";  //e.g test.sh -dparam1 -oout.txt
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this, it will work.

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "path/to/script.sh"};
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```